# Gitlab Runner - Is it possible to use a PVC for ephemeral storage and if so which path should I target?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an ierror with my GitlabCI pipeline pods, which are failing due to low ephemeral storage:

Pipeline logs:

```
ERROR: Job failed: pod "runner-pannpiuz-project-522-concurrent-0-bwxxxxxx" status is "Failed"
```

Pod events:

```
2m7s        Warning   Evicted     pod/runner-pannpiuz-project-522-concurrent-0-bwxxxxxx   The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container helper was using 48Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container build was using 229896Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
2m7s        Normal    Killing     pod/runner-pannpiuz-project-522-concurrent-0-bwxxxxxx   Stopping container build
2m7s        Normal    Killing     pod/runner-pannpiuz-project-522-concurrent-0-bwxxxxxx   Stopping container helper
```

I have checked the space on the pod for the GitLab runner and indeed it shows some directories that are near full capacity:

```
kubectl  -n gitlab-runner exec -it gitlab-runner-7xxxxxxx-txxxx
 df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                  49.0G     23.0G     23.4G  50% /
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    15.6G      4.0K     15.6G   0% /secrets
/dev/root                15.6G     12.4G      2.4G  84% /configmaps
/dev/sdb1                49.0G     23.0G     23.4G  50% /etc/hostname
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1                49.0G     23.0G     23.4G  50% /etc/gitlab-runner
/dev/root                15.6G     12.4G      2.4G  84% /etc/hosts
/dev/root                15.6G     12.4G      2.4G  84% /dev/termination-log
/dev/sdb1                49.0G     23.0G     23.4G  50% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/sdb1                49.0G     23.0G     23.4G  50% /home/gitlab-runner
tmpfs                    15.6G      8.0K     15.6G   0% /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner
tmpfs                    15.6G      4.0K     15.6G   0% /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/certs
tmpfs                    15.6G     12.0K     15.6G   0% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/latency_stats
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                     7.8G         0      7.8G   0% /sys/firmware
```

According to research I have carried out I have a variety of options to fix this issue:

- Add LimitRanges
- Add Ephemeral Storage limits and requests on the Helm chart
- Use a PVC for storage

From these options I have some constraints and I can only introduce a PVC for now, which should provide extra space.

My questions:

1. If I am to add a PVC to the Gitlab runner Helm chart which path should I mount on that PVC. From the output of `df -h` I can see that they are 3 paths that are near full capacity but ***I am not sure which path corresponds to ephemeral storage***.

The path `/configmaps` seems the most logical (at least for now) but then the ConfigMap is already mounted as a volume of type ConfigMap as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gitlab-debug-runner
  namespace: gitlab-debug-runner
  labels:
    app: gitlab-debug-runner
    chart: gitlab-runner-0.38.1
    release: "gitlab-runner"
    heritage: "Helm"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gitlab-debug-runner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gitlab-debug-runner
        chart: gitlab-runner-0.38.1
        release: "gitlab-runner"
        heritage: "Helm"
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/port: "9252"
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 100
        fsGroup: 65533
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600
      initContainers:
      - name: configure
        command: ['sh', '/configmaps/configure']
        image: docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v14.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          
        env:
                
        - name: CI_SERVER_URL
          value: "https://mycompany.com/"
        - name: CLONE_URL
          value: ""
        - name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
          value: "kubernetes"
        - name: REGISTER_LOCKED
          value: "true"
        - name: RUNNER_TAG_LIST
          value: "debug,development,k8s"
        - name: RUNNER_OUTPUT_LIMIT
          value: "4096"
        - name: KUBERNETES_IMAGE
          value: "ubuntu:20.04"
        - name: KUBERNETES_PRIVILEGED
          value: "true"
        - name: KUBERNETES_POLL_TIMEOUT
          value: "180"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: runner-secrets
          mountPath: /secrets
          readOnly: false
        - name: configmaps
          mountPath: /configmaps
          readOnly: true
        - name: init-runner-secrets
          mountPath: /init-secrets
          readOnly: true
        resources:
          {}
      serviceAccountName: gitlab-debug-runner
      containers:
      - name: gitlab-debug-runner
        image: docker.io/gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v14.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          runAsNonRoot: true

        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/entrypoint", "unregister", "--all-runners"]
        command: ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--", "/bin/bash", "/configmaps/entrypoint"]
        env:
                
        - name: CI_SERVER_URL
          value: "https://mycompany.com"
        - name: RUNNER_EXECUTOR
          value: "kubernetes"
        - name: REGISTER_LOCKED
          value: "true"
        - name: RUNNER_TAG_LIST
          value: "debug,development,k8s"
  
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/bash", "/configmaps/check-live"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/usr/bin/pgrep","gitlab.*runner"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 3
        ports:
        - name: "metrics"
          containerPort: 9252
        volumeMounts:
        - name: runner-secrets
          mountPath: /secrets
        - name: etc-gitlab-runner
          mountPath: /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner
        - name: configmaps
          mountPath: /configmaps
        resources:
          {}
      volumes:
      - name: runner-secrets
        emptyDir:
          medium: "Memory"
      - name: etc-gitlab-runner
        emptyDir:
          medium: "Memory"
      - name: init-runner-secrets
        projected:
          sources:
            - secret:
                name: "gitlab-debug-runner"
                items:
                  - key: runner-registration-token
                    path: runner-registration-token
                  - key: runner-token
                    path: runner-token
      - name: configmaps
        configMap:
          name: gitlab-debug-runner
```

2. If I am going to adjust Ephemeral storage's requests and limits, which values should I re use. The Helm chart contains too many options and I am not even sure which parameters to override.

[Ephemeral Limits & Requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#cpu-requests-and-limits)